# Amazon AWS - Gunicorn Starts on Boot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, gateway

Trying to deploy gunicorn auto boot on Amazon AWS (for reference, following along with TDD for Python [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch08.html#_using_upstart_to_make_sure_gunicorn_starts_on_boot)).

Site deploys fine with gunicorn when running:

```
../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind \ unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket.myapp.wsgi:application
```

But when trying to implement gunicorn to start with boot, i.e. running as: sudo start gunicorn-mysite.com , getting '**502 Bad Gateway(nginx)**'.

A few things:

1. Running off EC2 Amazon AWS
2. gunicorn version = 1.8

**/etc/init/gunicorn-mysite.com.conf**

```
description "Gunicorn server for mysite.com"

start on net-device-up

stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid ubuntu

chdir /home/ubuntu/sites/mysite.com/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \ 
--bind unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket \ 
myapp.wsgi:application
```

The logs are showing the following:

**/var/log/upstart**
**

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS][APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: No application module specified
```

**

**/var/log/nginx**

**`...[error] 6282#0 : * connect() to unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream client 10.10.100.100, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket:/", host: "mysite.com"`**

I'm running gunicorn with the following commands:

```
(virtualenv)ubuntu@/source$ sudo service nginx restart
(virtualenv)ubuntu@/source$ sudo starg gunicorn-mysite.com
```

Not sure why I'm getting bad gateway--any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \ 
--bind unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket \ 
myapp.wsgi:application
```

Replace `myapp.wsgi` with the name of you entry python file, replace `application` with the name defined in your python file.

For example, if there is a `run.py` in `/home/ubuntu/sites/mysite.com/source` like below:

```
from src import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can change your configuration like following:

```
exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \ 
--bind unix:/tmp/mysite.com.socket \ 
run:app
```